# Is my calculation correct about a probability problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

Suppose there are $300$ tickets in the pool, where $7$ of them belong to me. $20$ tickets are randomly taken out of the pool, and are declared as "winning tickets". What is the probability that *exactly* 4 of the winning tickets are mine?

When I tried to solve this I found
$$\frac{\binom{20}{4} \left(7 \times 6 \times 5 \times 4 \prod _{j=1}^{16} (-j+293+1)\right)}{\prod _{i=1}^{20} (-i+300+1)} \approx 0.000433665 $$
Is this the correct probability?

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: the way to think about this is to begin with the notion that there are $\binom{300}{20}$ possible subsets of $20$ tickets that could be declared as winning tickets, and then think about how many of these subsets consist of exactly $4$ out of your $7$ tickets (doesn't matter which $4$) and $16$ of the other $293$ tickets (again, does not matter which $16$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $\binom{300}{20}$ ways to make the choice of winning tickets. There are $\binom74\binom{293}{16}$ ways to choose them so that exactly $4$ of the winning tickets are among your $7$ tickets. The desired probability is therefore

$$\frac{\binom74\binom{293}{16}}{\binom{300}{20}}\approx0.000433665\;.$$

You did it the hard way, at least from my point of view, but you got there okay.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct but the way it is notated is not very elegant.

I should choose to write it as:

> $$\frac{\binom{20}{4}\binom{280}{3}}{\binom{300}{7}}$$

Choosing $7$ from $300$ gives $\binom{300}{7}$ possibilities. $4$ of them belonging to your $20$ gives $\binom{20}{4}$ possibilities and $3$ of them belonging to the $280$ that are not yours gives $\binom{280}{3}$ possibilities.